# Combinational loop in a program

Tags: verilog, quartus

There is a error in the program and I'm sure it's caused by `negedge iChang` in the always block. The error is:

> Zero-time oscillation in node....... Check the design or vector source file for combinational loop.

My partial program is as follow:

```
input  clk, rst,iChang;
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst or negedge iChang)
    begin 
        if(!iChang)//auto mode,serious problems!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            begin
                if(!rst)
                    begin
                        s1<=state1;
                        A<=3'b0;
                        B<=3'b0;
                        count1<=3'd4;
                        count2<=3'd2;
                        count3<=3'd3;
                        count4<=3'd2;
                        temp<=1'b1;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        if(temp==1)
                            begin
                                temp<=1'b0;
                                case(s1)
                                    state1:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count1;
                                            A<=3'b001;
                                            B<=3'b100;
                                            s1<=state2;
                                        end
                                    state2:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count2;
                                            A<=3'b010;
                                            B<=3'b100;
                                            s1<=state3;             
                                        end
                                    state3:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count3;
                                            A<=3'b100;
                                            B<=3'b001;
                                            s1<=state4;

                                        end
                                    state4:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count4;
                                            A<=3'b100;
                                            B<=3'b010;
                                            s1<=state1;
                                        end
                                    default:
                                        begin
                                            A<=3'b000;
                                            B<=3'b000;
                                        end
                                    endcase
                            end
```

If I remove `negedge iChang` in the `always` block and the `if(!iChang)` block ,there will be no error. I don't understand the relation between the `negedge iChang` and the combination loop. It seemed that there is no feedback can cause combination loop.

Comment: Where does `iChang` come from?

Comment: It is an input(button)，and is used to trigger the always block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edge-triggered always blocks are used for synchronous logic. It should have a clock reference and it may have one asynchronous reset and may have one asynchronous set. Based on your code, it looks like `iChang` should be sampled on `posedge clk`, so it should not be in the sensitivity list. I believe you are confusing sensitivity list requirements of synchronous always blocks with the IEEE1364-1995 style of combinational always blocks. IEEE1364-1995 style combinational always blocks require all inputs signals to be listed in the sensitivity list. <sub>(Recommend useing IEEE1364-2001's auto-sensitivity list (`@*`/`@(*)`) for combinational always blocks)</sub>

Assuming you want an asynchronous reset, then your always blocks should look like:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin 
  if(!rst) begin
    // ... reset code ...
  end
  else if (!iChang) begin
    // ... synchronous code ...
  end
end
```

If you truely want `iChang` to prevent a reset, then make the reset synchronous as well:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin 
  if (!iChang) begin
    if(!rst) begin
      // ... reset code ...
    end
    else begin
      // ... synchronous code ...
    end
  end
end
```